# "This" in Spanish in the context of "this bad"

Tags: traducción

I understand "**this**" translates into **esto** in Spanish. However in the following contexts, that translation doesn't seem to work:

> How did you manage to hurt your back this bad?
>
> Whoa! I didn't know you cooked that good!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can substitute it directly by *así de* or *tan* (*bien/mal/rápido/etc.*) when modifying a noun/adjective. When modifying a verb you can use *tanto* (after the verb):

```
Cómo lograste hacerte tanto daño en la espalda?
Cómo conseguiste lastimarte tanto la espalda?
Cómo hiciste para dejarte la espalda así de mal?

¡Vaya! ¡No sabía que cocinabas así de bien!
¡Anda! ¡No sabía que cocinabas tan bien!
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably use tanto or tan as a good substitute